# Ultravnc is not able to connect,no error message is shown

Tags: remote-access, ultravnc

I am using UltraVnc to connect to my cutomers. But in some cases we are unable to connect to customer. In customer side he is able to see the authentication ID. If firewall or antivirus will be blocking then he will not be able to see that and get some error messages. But in this case no error message is shown. In viewer when we put the ID and connect it tries to keep on connecting , but does not connect Also no message is shown.

So i am not able to troubleshoot the said problem. What may be the problem causing this?
We are using vncviewer of version 1.0.9.6 and winvnc is of latest version 1.1.9.4

Answer (score 0):

If you solely use "UltraVNC" then, in most cases, this will simply not work because of NAT (Network Address translation) and other things like port blocking and firewalls.

If you are looking for a system that can traverse NATed networks or work through firewalls then there are solutions out there such as TeamViewer, BOMGAR, LogMeIn etc. that have been designed to work in situations like yours. They are "paid-for" services but if you are serious about offering remote support to your customers you shouldn't get them to reconfigure their own equipment. Many simply haven't got the expertise to do this, or risk opening their networks up to major security breaches and holes.

Comment: If firewall blocks it then it shows error like "not able to connect" or "server closed connection" etc. In this cases there was no such error.